# Send Table cell value to Servlet Through ajax

Tags: ajax

I need to post values from a table cell to a servet through Ajax but the response is returning a null. My Javascript is not that strong and I am certainly doing something wrong and need some direction. Below are my JSP and Ajax script:

```
**My  JSP code**
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" class="itemData" tableData="${item}" onclick="saveData()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button> </td>  

**My Ajax  code**
function saveData(){
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     var dataID = $(this).attr('tableData');
        $.ajax({
            url : 'DataCtrlServlet',
            type: 'Post',
            data : dataID,
            success : function(responseText) {
                $('#submissionSuccessContainer').text(responseText);
            }
        });
     return false;   



 }); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Romve `return false;` and `$(document).ready` ,also you need to change the `data` format to pass the parameter correctly

```
function saveData(){
    var dataID = $(this).attr('tableData');
    $.ajax({
        url : 'DataCtrlServlet',
        type: 'Post',
        data : {
           dataID:dataID
        },
        success : function(responseText) {
            $('#submissionSuccessContainer').text(responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Accepted! Your  suggestion solved my problem.  Thank You so much.